# VBA excel macro for a button that selects named reference from a named range

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a named range "last_monday", which dynamically calculates one variable, last monday's date ("d-mmm-yy").  I'd like a macro that I can assign to a button which would select the column where last monday's date resides within a broader range of column-wise dates, called "date_range".

E.g. assuming today's date is Monday, 15-Jan-18, the button would select the cell in position BQ5 in the example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below selects the cell in `Date_Range` indicated by the value of `Last_Monday`. If there is no match it does nothing.

```
Sub SelectMonday()

    Dim C As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    C = Application.Match(Range("Last_Monday").Value2, Range("Date_Range"), 0)
    If C Then Range("Date_Range").Cells(C).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great.  I'm wondering, how do I assign this to a button object?  When I right-click the button and choose assign macro, I don't see SelectMonday in the list of available macros.

Comment: My apologies! You did say that you wanted to assign the macro to a button. For that purpose it shouldn't be a function. I have modified my original answer changing the procedure into a sub which you will see listed so long as it is stored in a standard code module.